# R: How to elegantly separate code logic from UI / html-tags?

Tags: r, shiny, templating, htmltools

### Problem

When dynamically creating ui-elements (`shiny.tag`, `shiny.tag.list`, ...), I often find it difficult to separate it from my code logic and usually end up with a convoluted mess of nested `tags$div(...)`, mixed with loops and conditional statements. While annoying and ugly to look at, it's also error-prone, e.g. when making changes to html-templates.

### Reproducible example

Let's say I have the following data-structure:

```
my_data <- list(
  container_a = list(
    color = "orange",
    height = 100,
    content = list(
      vec_a = c(type = "p", value = "impeach"),
      vec_b = c(type = "h1", value = "orange")
    )
  ),
  container_b = list(
    color = "yellow",
    height = 50,
    content = list(
      vec_a = c(type = "p", value = "tool")
    )
  )  
)
```

If I now want to push this structure into ui-tags, I usually end up with something like:

```
library(shiny)

my_ui <- tagList(
  tags$div(
    style = "height: 400px; background-color: lightblue;",
    lapply(my_data, function(x){
      tags$div(
        style = paste0("height: ", x$height, "px; background-color: ", x$color, ";"),
        lapply(x$content, function(y){
          if (y[["type"]] == "h1") {
            tags$h1(y[["value"]])
          } else if (y[["type"]] == "p") {
            tags$p(y[["value"]])
          }
        }) 
      )
    })
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(my_ui, server)
```

As you can see, this already is quite messy and still nothing compared to my real like examples.

### Desired solution

I was hoping to find something close to a **templating engine** for R, that would allow to define **templates and data separately**:

```
# syntax, borrowed from handlebars.js
my_template <- tagList(
  tags$div(
    style = "height: 400px; background-color: lightblue;",
    "{{#each my_data}}",
    tags$div(
      style = "height: {{this.height}}px; background-color: {{this.color}};",
      "{{#each this.content}}",
      "{{#if this.content.type.h1}}",
      tags$h1("this.content.type.h1.value"),
      "{{else}}",
      tags$p(("this.content.type.p.value")),
      "{{/if}}",      
      "{{/each}}"
    ),
    "{{/each}}"
  )
)
```

### Previous attempts

First, I thought that `shiny::htmlTemplate()` could offer a solution, but this would only work with files and text strings, not `shiny.tag`s. I also had a look at some r-packages like [whisker](https://github.com/edwindj/whisker)
, but those seems to have the same limitation and do not support tags or list-structures.

Thank you!

Comment: You could save a css file under `www` folder and then apply the style sheets?

Comment: In the case of applying css, sure, but I was looking for a general approach that allows for changes in html-structure, etc.

Comment: Nothing useful to add but upvoting and commenting in commiseration. Ideally, `htmlTemplate()` would allow for conditionals and loops ala handlebars, mustache, twig...

Answer (score 3):

I like creating composable and reusable UI elements using functions that produce Shiny HTML tags (or `htmltools` tags). From your example app, I could identify a "page" element, and then two generic content containers, and then create some functions for those:

```
library(shiny)

my_page <- function(...) {
  div(style = "height: 400px; background-color: lightblue;", ...)
}

my_content <- function(..., height = NULL, color = NULL) {
  style <- paste(c(
    sprintf("height: %spx", height),
    sprintf("background-color: %s", color)
  ), collapse = "; ")

  div(style = style, ...)
}
```

And then I could compose my UI with something like this:

```
my_ui <- my_page(
  my_content(
    p("impeach"),
    h1("orange"),
    color = "orange",
    height = 100
  ),
  my_content(
    p("tool"),
    color = "yellow",
    height = 50
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(my_ui, server)
```

Any time I need to tweak the styling or HTML of an element, I'd just go straight to the function that generates that element.

Also, I've just inlined the data in this case. I think the data structure in your example really mixes data with UI concerns (styling, HTML tags), which might explain some of the convoluted-ness. The only data I see is "orange" as the header, and "impeach"/"tool" as the content.

If you have more complicated data or need more specific UI components, you can use functions again like building blocks:

```
my_content_card <- function(title = "", content = "") {
  my_content(
    h1(title),
    p(content),
    color = "orange",
    height = 100
  )
}

my_ui <- my_page(
  my_content_card(title = "impeach", content = "orange"),
  my_content(
    p("tool"),
    color = "yellow",
    height = 50
  )
)
```

Hope that helps. If you're looking for better examples, you can check out the source code behind Shiny's input and output elements (e.g. [`selectInput()`](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/master/R/input-select.R)), which are essentially functions that spit out HTML tags. A templating engine could also work, but there's no real need when you've already got `htmltools` + the full power of R.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I used to do it like this as well, but it becomes quite impractical when much of the html cannot be reused. I guess some kind of template-engine would be the only viable solution :/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could consider looking into `glue()` and `get()`.

**get():**

`get()` can turn strings into variables/objects.

So you could shorten:

```
if (y[["type"]] == "h1") {
    tags$h1(y[["value"]])
} else if (y[["type"]] == "p") {
    tags$p(y[["value"]])
}
```

to

```
get(y$type)(y$value)
```

(see the example below).

**glue():**

`glue()` provides an alternative to `paste0()`. It could be more readable if you concentenate lots of strings and variables to a string. I assume it also looks close to the syntax of your desired result.

Instead of:

```
paste0("height: ", x$height, "px; background-color: ", x$color, ";")
```

You would write:

```
glue("height:{x$height}px; background-color:{x$color};")
```

Your example would simplify to:

```
tagList(
  tags$div(style = "height: 400px; background-color: lightblue;",
    lapply(my_data, function(x){
      tags$div(style = glue("height:{x$height}px; background-color:{x$color};"),
        lapply(x$content, function(y){get(y$type)(y$value)}) 
      )
    })
  )
)
```

Using:

```
library(glue)
my_data <- list(
  container_a = list(
    color = "orange",
    height = 100,
    content = list(
      vec_a = list(type = "p", value = "impeach"),
      vec_b = list(type = "h1", value = "orange")
    )
  ),
  container_b = list(
    color = "yellow",
    height = 50,
    content = list(
      vec_a = list(type = "p", value = "tool")
    )
  )  
)
```

**Alternatives:**

I think htmltemplate is a good idea, but another problem are the undesired whitespaces: https://github.com/rstudio/htmltools/issues/19#issuecomment-252957684.

Comment: Thanks for your input. While your code is more compact, the issue of mixing html and logic remains. :/